# Jquery ajax when

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am using jquery when to wait until an ajax function is finished and then publish the results of the function in a test div. I am using an interval to repeat the process every 5 seconds. The results I am getting are undefined and then the id of the json element.

Here is my code.

```
shortWVCInterval = setInterval(defferedAjax, 5000);
GLB_VAR = "None";

function defferedAjax(){
    $.when(checkAjax()).done(function(){
    $('#test').append(GLB_VAR.id + " - ");
  });
}

function checkAjax(){
    var url = "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts";
  $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: url,
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(data) {
            GLB_VAR = data;
        }
    });
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/Lh2q5c4t/

How do I get the Id on the first interval?

Comment: you don't need the `$.when()`

Comment: @KevinB Thanks for elaborating.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

here the working code:

```
shortWVCInterval = setInterval(defferedAjax, 5000);
GLB_VAR = "None";

function defferedAjax(){
    $.when(checkAjax()).done(function(){
    $('#test').append(GLB_VAR.id + " - ");
  });
}

function checkAjax(){
     return $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts",
        dataType: 'json',
    success: function(data) {
        GLB_VAR = data;
    }
});
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/Lh2q5c4t/3/

**Edit :** you must add "return $.ajax", "The return statement stops the execution of a function and returns a value from that function."

Comment: Not sure why. Thanks for the answer!

Comment: @lefdilia I didn't downvote, but consider to explain your answer instead of just writing code. That will make it more useful and you will get up- instead of downvotes for correct answers

Comment: Exactly what you have commented now belongs to your answer, not in a comment